# Jupyter notebook : Server Error while accessing notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04

I'm facing the following error while trying to upload or access any file in my Jupyter notebook. NOTE: I'm using an Ubuntu 18.04 VM and Jupyter Notebook 5.7.4.

> Server error: Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/home/abhi1507/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py",
>   line 1592, in _execute result = yield result File
>   "/home/abhi1507/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py",
>   line 1133, in run value = future.result() File
>   "/home/abhi1507/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py",
>   line 326, in wrapper yielded = next(result) File
>   "/home/abhi1507/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py",
>   line 112, in get path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content,
>   File
>   "/home/abhi1507/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py",
>   line 431, in get model = self._dir_model(path, content=content) File
>   "/home/abhi1507/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py",
>   line 337, in _dir_model if self.should_list(name) and not
>   is_file_hidden(os_path, stat_res=st): File
>   "/home/abhi1507/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/utils.py",
>   line 146, in is_file_hidden_posix stat_res = os.stat(abs_path)
>   OSError: [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links:
>   '/home/abhi1507/q3.sh' AD

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the same thing, but I suddenly had all my jupyter notebooks in new conda environments start breaking today.  Eventually found this worked:

```
pip uninstall tornado
pip install tornado==5.1.1
```

Jupyter Notebooks and Tornado both released new versions in the past week (circa 2019-03-01) - I think one or both is the problem.  If tornado doesn't work, I'd try the same idea but downgrading jupyter (or both).

**Edit:** Actual cause/fix described [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4311#issuecomment-470151566).  Can fix the issue by updating nbconvert to v5.4.1:

```
pip install --upgrade nbconvert
```